# Html form validation does not work when i am using javascript to submit my forms to json

Tags: javascript, html, json

I am making a form which on submitting submits my form to a JSON file however, when i used JavaScript to submit my forms to my JSON file i noticed that form validations like required and others does not work so i wanted to know to be able to send my data to JSON as well as having HTML form validations as well. Can someone tell how i can do that?

```js
const send = document.querySelector('.send-message');

send.addEventListener("click", async e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    var name = document.querySelector(".contactName").value;
    var email = document.querySelector(".contactEmail").value;
    var number = document.querySelector(".contactNumber").value;
    var message = document.querySelector(".contactMessage").value;
    const contact = {
        name,
        email,
        number,
        message
    }
    let response = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/contact', 
        {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(contact)
        });
        alert("Thanks for contacting Us");
});
```

```css
.Contact-input_area label {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 1.5;
}
.Contact-input_area input,
.Contact-input_textarea textarea {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  color: #000;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  padding: 16px;
  border: 1px solid#ced4da;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 24px;
  transition: border-color 0.15s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.5s ease-in-out;
  font-family: "Raleway", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
.Contact-input_area input:focus {
  box-shadow: none;
  border-color: #379cf4;
}
.Contact-input_textarea textarea:focus {
  box-shadow: none;
  border-color: #379cf4;
}
.send_message button {
  background: #379cf4;
  border: 2px solid #379cf4;
  color: #fff;
  width: 40%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 15px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 500;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.9s;
}
.send_message button:hover {
  background: transparent;
  border: 2px solid #00baeb;
  color: #00baeb;
  border-radius: 15px;
}
```

```html
<form name="Contact">
              <p class="Contact-input_area">
                <label for="name">Name</label>
                <input
                  id="name"
                  name="name"
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="Your Name"
                  required
                  autocomplete="off"
                  autofocus=""
                  class="contactName"
                />
              </p>
              <p class="Contact-input_area">
                <label for="email">Email</label>
                <input
                  id="email"
                  name="email"
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="Your Email"
                  required
                  autocomplete="off"
                  class="contactEmail"
                />
              </p>
              <p class="Contact-input_area">
                <label for="number">Phone Number</label>
                <input
                  id="number"
                  name="number"
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="Your Phone"
                  required
                  autocomplete="off"
                  class="contactNumber"
                />
              </p>
              <p class="Contact-input_textarea">
                <label for="message">Message</label>
                <textarea
                  name="message"
                  id="message"
                  placeholder="Your Message"
                  cols="40"
                  rows="6"
                  required
                  autocomplete="off"
                  class="contactMessage"
                ></textarea>
              </p>
              <div class="send_message">
                <button type="submit" class="send-message">Send Message</button>
              </div>
            </form>
```

My JSON File:

```
  "contact": [
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "a",
  "email": "a@gmail.com",
  "number": "0000000000",
  "message": "Hello"
}]
```

Comment: You should bind the event to form on submit, not the button click event. https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onsubmit.asp

Comment: @AlvinStefanus now data are not going to the json file. can you do it and show to me.

Comment: Sorry but I do not quite understand about what goes into json file. Do you mean the response from the server is incorrect? Can you debug the `const contact`? Does it show the correct result?

Comment: when i hit submit it just refreshes the page and i have attached my json data above.

Comment: When you debug the code, does the submit event get called?

Comment: i found the problem now the problem was that await can only be used with aync now it was removed so it was not working. Thanks it worked.

Comment: Your `const contact` will not produce the correct `JSON string`, you should be writing, `const contact = { id: 1, name: name, email: email, number: number, message: message };`. This is assuming that your `contact` is an object, if you want this to be an array, you should declare your contact as an array, then push the form object into it.

Comment: I will put the worked solution as an answer below

Comment: @AlvinStefanus I have a diffrent json file i am not doing it in javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the credit for solving this problem goes to Alvin Stefanus.Thanks Man.

```js
async function ContactFormSubmit(){
    var name = document.querySelector(".contactName").value;
    var email = document.querySelector(".contactEmail").value;
    var number = document.querySelector(".contactNumber").value;
    var message = document.querySelector(".contactMessage").value;
    const contact = {
        name,
        email,
        number,
        message
    }
    let response =await fetch('http://localhost:3000/contact', 
        {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(contact)
        });
        alert("Thanks for contacting Us");
}
```

```css
.contact-input {
  width: 50%;
  padding: 30px;
}
.Contact-input_area label {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 1.5;
}
.Contact-input_area input,
.Contact-input_textarea textarea {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  color: #000;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  padding: 16px;
  border: 1px solid#ced4da;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 24px;
  transition: border-color 0.15s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.5s ease-in-out;
  font-family: "Raleway", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
.Contact-input_area input:focus {
  box-shadow: none;
  border-color: #379cf4;
}
.Contact-input_textarea textarea:focus {
  box-shadow: none;
  border-color: #379cf4;
}
.send_message button {
  background: #379cf4;
  border: 2px solid #379cf4;
  color: #fff;
  width: 40%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 15px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 500;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.9s;
}
.send_message button:hover {
  background: transparent;
  border: 2px solid #00baeb;
  color: #00baeb;
  border-radius: 15px;
}
```

```html
            <form name="Contact"  onsubmit="ContactFormSubmit()">
              <p class="Contact-input_area">
                <label for="name">Name</label>
                <input
                  id="name"
                  name="name"
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="Your Name"
                  required
                  autocomplete="off"
                  autofocus=""
                  class="contactName"
                />
              </p>
              <p class="Contact-input_area">
                <label for="email">Email</label>
                <input
                  id="email"
                  name="email"
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="Your Email"
                  required
                  autocomplete="off"
                  class="contactEmail"
                />
              </p>
              <p class="Contact-input_area">
                <label for="number">Phone Number</label>
                <input
                  id="number"
                  name="number"
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="Your Phone"
                  required
                  autocomplete="off"
                  class="contactNumber"
                />
              </p>
              <p class="Contact-input_textarea">
                <label for="message">Message</label>
                <textarea
                  name="message"
                  id="message"
                  placeholder="Your Message"
                  cols="40"
                  rows="6"
                  required
                  autocomplete="off"
                  class="contactMessage"
                ></textarea>
              </p>
              <div class="send_message">
                <button type="submit" class="send-message">Send Message</button>
              </div>
            </form>
```

My Json data goes something like this:

```
  "contact": [
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "a",
  "email": "a@gmail.com",
  "number": "0000000000",
  "message": "Hello"
}
```

]